# How to test app without pebble watch?

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have to add a feature for the Pebble smart watch in my android app. Is there any cloud or emulators available to test Pebble watch coding?  How can I test my app without a Pebble watch ?

Comment: see this https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples  and this https://github.com/pebble/pebblekit/blob/master/Android/PebbleKitExample/src/com/example/PebbleKitExample/ExampleGCMActivity.java

Comment: I need testing device like emulator for bebble watch

Comment: @user3057145, Pebble does not provide a watch emulator.

Comment: (via [David Stosik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2341409/david-stosik)'s answer below) About a year after this question was asked, Pebble integrated a QEMU watch emulator into their online IDE [CloudPebble](https://cloudpebble.net/ide/).

Answer (score 8):

This question is a bit old, and that's probably the reason why nobody answered with CloudPebble yet.

Since Jan. 24th 2015, CloudPebble includes an emulator that allows you to run your app pretty quickly in your browser.
You have to login with your Pebble ids at https://cloudpebble.net/ide/ , import or create a new project, then you can go to Compilation > Emulator, then click "Install and run".

CloudPebble works for C SDK apps, Simply.js and Pebble.js apps too.

Answer (score 6):

Since the release of the developer preview of the SDK 3.0 and as an alternative to CloudPebble you can also install the Pebble emulator based on QEMU.

Follow this [instructions](https://developer.rebble.io/developer.pebble.com/sdk/install/linux/index.html) for linux (Mac and Win also available).

Then after building your app you can install it in the emulator as follows:

```
pebble install --emulator basalt /[your project path]/build/[Your app name].pbw
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a very nice Pebble simulator at
https://github.com/Helco/PebbleLocalSim
It only seems to work with the C SDK, I can't find a way of running pebble.js javaScript, which is a shame.

Answer (score -2):

There are no emulators out there to test Pebble apps. At the very least you could test the javascript end of a Pebble app with simulated data from the watch. Beyond that you need a Pebble watch to work with.